# amsmath align environment: row spacing

Tags: spacing, amsmath, align

How can I stretch the spacing between consecutive lines in an `align*` environment? I have a few lines with `\frac`s in which both the numerator and the denominator consist of textual phrases, not math symbols, and the result looks too cluttered.

```
\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{\textit{Some text here}}{\textit{And some text here}}\\
Y &= \frac{\textit{Will make everything}}{\textit{Look too close together}}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You could add space manually like so:

```
\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{\textit{Some text here}}{\textit{And some text here}}\\[1em]
Y &= \frac{\textit{Will make everything}}{\textit{Look too close together}}
\end{align*}
```

change `[1em]` to suit how much space you want.

Thanks to Ian Thompson in the comments for pointing me to this slightly more elegant solution. If you want to add a little extra spacing to every row of an align:

```
\begingroup
\addtolength{\jot}{1em}
\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{\textit{Some text here}}{\textit{And some text here}}\\
Y &= \frac{\textit{Will make everything}}{\textit{Look too close together}}
\end{align*}
\endgroup
```

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are to keep the extra alignment local to the environment. If you want all align environments to have the extra spacing, add `\addtolength{\jot}{1em}` to your preamble instead.

Comment: @Thomas this is a pretty crude way to do things. I expect there are cleverer ways like redefining `\arraystretch` locally or some such... But that's for array not align...

Comment: @Seamus: Yeah, I was looking for something like `\arraystretch`, but adding space manually works perfectly fine for my case.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for accepting, but it is customary to wait a while before accepting an answer: someone might suggest a better answer! Also, if it's good enough to accept, it should probably be good enough to upvote...

Comment: @Seamus: I have no problems with accepting a better answer if one comes along.

Comment: @Thomas fair enough, but people are less likely to answer a question if it already has an accepted answer.

Comment: @Seamus, @Thomas: I think `\jot` is the nearest thing to `\arraystretch` for this case. `\addtolength{\jot}{1em}` adds `1em` to the default spacing between the rows.

Comment: the \jot solution is already available through the `mathtools` package as the `spreadlines` environment, makes the structure a bit 'nicer'

Comment: What does `\jot` stand for? It seems like such an arbitrary name.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jot gives two definitions of "jot" ("the least bit" and "write briefly or hurriedly").  I could see either of them inspiring the command name.