# Unable to \addtolength{\jot} using acmart

Tags: align, vertical-spacing, acmart

I’m using the `acmart` document class and would like to adjust the row height globally in various `align` environments. However I seem to be unable to use `\addtolength` to modify `\jot`, which I believe is the [recommended approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/amsmath-align-environment-row-spacing). Here’s roughly what I’d like to achieve, hacked in manually using `[0.5em]` or `[-0.5em]` on a line-by-line basis:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{acmart}

% these don’t seem to do anything
% \addtolength{\jot}{0.5em}
% \addtolength{\jot}{-0.5em}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   Here’s
   \\
   the
   \\
   default
   \\
   spacing
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   Want
   \\[-0.5em]
   to
   \\[-0.5em]
   have
   \\[-0.5em]
   smaller
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   Want
   \\[0.5em]
   to
   \\[0.5em]
   have
   \\[0.5em]
   bigger
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I’ve checked that `\addtolength` works as expected using `article`:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   Here's
   \\
   the
   \\
   default
   \\
   spacing
\end{align}

\addtolength{\jot}{-0.5em}
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   smaller
\end{align}

\addtolength{\jot}{1em}
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   bigger
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How can I make this work with `acmart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change `\jot`, but use `\openup`.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   Here’s
   \\
   the
   \\
   default
   \\
   spacing
\end{align}

\begingroup\openup-\jot
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   smaller
\end{align}\endgroup

\begingroup\openup\jot
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   bigger
\end{align}\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's better to define a suitable environment for this. The argument can be any decimal number, positive for increasing the space, negative for decreasing it.

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\newenvironment{changespacing}[1]{\openup#1\jot}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   Here’s
   \\
   the
   \\
   default
   \\
   spacing
\end{align}

\begin{changespacing}{-1}
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   smaller
\end{align}
\end{changespacing}

\begin{changespacing}{1}
\begin{align}
   Want
   \\
   to
   \\
   have
   \\
   bigger
\end{align}
\end{changespacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I hadn’t come across `\openup` before.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to adjust `\jot` in the document before math environments, not in a preamble

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}

\addtolength{\jot}{5em}
\begin{align}
   Here’s
   \\
   the
   \\
   adjusted
   \\
   spacing
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! I did try that, but it didn’t work; it looks like it’s an interaction with a `newenvironment` definition I use. (I define `salign` as `\newenvironment{salign}
   {\par\nobreak\small\noindent\csname align*\endcsname}
   {\csname endalign*\endcsname}`. Anyway, if I use regular `align` then it works as per your example. Thanks again.